# Fetch a text from microsoft word with C# related to its font

Tags: c#, ms-word

I want to get a string from the text written in Microsoft Word. But only those words which are **bold**. I have taken everything written there with the code below but I don't know how to adjust it to take only the bold text.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
object path = @textBox1.Text;
object readOnly = true;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document docs = word.Documents.Open(ref path, ref miss, ref       readOnly, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);
string totaltext = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < docs.Paragraphs.Count; i++)
        {
               totaltext =  docs.Paragraphs[i+1].Range.Text.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply this piece of code to your `docs` object. You will get a `List` of text fragments.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rng = docs.Content;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Find find = rng.Find;

find.Font.Bold = 1;
find.Format = true;

List<string> bolds = new List<string>();
while (find.Execute())
{
    bolds.Add(rng.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application Objword = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> data = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

//creating the object of document class  
Document objdoc = new Document();
try
{
    //createting the object of application class  

    //get the uploaded file full path  
    dynamic FilePath = strfilename;

    // the optional (missing) parameter to API  
    dynamic NA = System.Type.Missing;

    //open Word file document 
    objdoc = Objword.Documents.Open
        (ref FilePath, ref NA, ref NA, ref NA, ref NA,
         ref NA, ref NA, ref NA, ref NA,
         ref NA, ref NA, ref NA, ref NA,
         ref NA, ref NA, ref NA);

    //creating the object of string builder class  
    // StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int Line = 0; Line < objdoc.Paragraphs.Count; Line++)
    {
        string Alignment = objdoc.Paragraphs[Line + 1].Format.Alignment.ToString();

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Style style2 = objdoc.Paragraphs[Line + 1].Format.get_Style();

        string Filedata = objdoc.Paragraphs[Line + 1].Range.Text.Replace("\r", "~").Replace("\t", "^");
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Style style = objdoc.Paragraphs[Line + 1].Range.get_Style();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Style baseStyle = style.get_BaseStyle();
        string font = style2.Font.Name.ToString();

        string spacing = style2.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing.ToString();
        string strstyle = style2.Description.ToString();

        data.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(Filedata, strstyle));

    }
```